# Drop-down list in Excel cell

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

I have a simple Excel speadsheet where in one column i write string values.
What I need is to define some predefined values and instead of typing string select
it from dropdown list. For instance for a column Store Name I want to select "Reebok", "Adidas" and so on.

I understand that there can be several ways how to implement it,even VBA. I use Office 2007.

Please advice.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/59870/setting-up-a-column-of-enum-fields-in-excel

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I do is have column A with all the values in, select the cells which need the list (or do this to one, and do the cell corner drag to the other cells), choose **Data** -> **Validation** from the menu (*Data Validation* on M), in Settings tab change Allow from "Any Value" to "List". Then click the button which appears next to the new entry box.

Select the cells in column A, then click the button again. Then click Ok.

Then hide Column A, so you can't see them (Just for display purposes).

You don't have to use Column A, it's just that way you don't have to worry about moving the list if your table extends down or outwards.

Comment: Right, I have found the solution that you have suggested
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052022151033.aspx